# Radio button validation before post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

I want to ensure that a user picks an answer to the question being asked. I have tried JQuery, Custom Validation class, setting model attributes to required. To summarise, if no radio button is selected, then the error message is shown and the user has to select an answer before progressing to the next question.

This is the HTML/Razor without the ValidationMessageFor, as it hasn't worked.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Question", "PreRegistration", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
 @if (Model.Questions.fldAnswerType == "Radio")
  {
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
                @{
                    if (Model.Questions.fldOption1 != null)
                    {
                        <div class="radio">
                            @Html.RadioButton("Radio", @Model.Questions.fldOption1, new { @class = "myGroup" }) @Model.Questions.fldOption1                             
                        </div>
                    }

                    if (Model.Questions.fldOption2 != null)
                    {
                        <div class="radio">
                            @Html.RadioButton("Radio", @Model.Questions.fldOption2, new { @class = "myGroup" }) @Model.Questions.fldOption2                             
                        </div>
                    }

                    if (Model.Questions.fldOption3 != null)
                    {
                        <div class="radio">
                            @Html.RadioButton("Radio", @Model.Questions.fldOption3, new { @class = "myGroup" }) @Model.Questions.fldOption3
                        </div>
                    }

                    if (Model.Questions.fldOption4 != null)
                    {
                        <div class="radio">
                            @Html.RadioButton("Radio", @Model.Questions.fldOption4) @Model.Questions.fldOption4
                        </div>
                    }

                    if (Model.Questions.fldOption5 != null)
                    {
                        <div class="radio">
                            @Html.RadioButton("Radio", @Model.Questions.fldOption5) @Model.Questions.fldOption5
                        </div>
                    }

                    if (Model.Questions.fldOption6 != null)
                    {
                        <div class="radio">
                            @Html.RadioButton("Radio", @Model.Questions.fldOption6) @Model.Questions.fldOption6
                        </div>

                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
<input type="submit" value="Next" id="btn" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

I have spent all day trying to get it to work but I can't...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Question(FormCollection collection, Questions questions)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     var viewModel = new RegistrationViewModel
      {
        Questions = questions,
        Responses = response
      };

     return View("Question", viewModel);
   }
 }
```

The question Model I am posting back is always null, so I am assuming this is the reason why the model state is always valid?

Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: It has nothing to do with `ModelState` being invalid. You have multiple problems - for a start you have nested forms which is invalid html. And if the model is `null` its because your not binding to your model (but you have not even bothered to show it). Does your model really contain a property named `Radio`? (clearly it does not)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
HttpPost] public ActionResult Question(FormCollection collection, Questions questions)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var viewModel = new RegistrationViewModel { Questions = questions, Responses = response };
        return View("Question", viewModel);
    }
}
Response.next page
```

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with the question!

Comment: This won't even compile.